# Built-in: Explorer and Built-in: Fuzz are not able to click on the permission dialog box that appears when the app gets launched

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

We are trying to test our application on AWS Device Farm using Built-in: Explorer and Fuzz tests provided by AWS Device Farm but they are not able to click on the permission dialog box when the app launches. The testing of the application works fine for android versions below 6.0 because android used to give permissions by default requested by the app. Is there any work around to this problem?

Comment: What you could probably do then is author a adb monkey test command in the custom environment and then before the tests start execute a different adb command to give chrome that permission. 

That solution wouldn't work for the explorer tests though since those tests aren't publicly available.  

Is this something that would work for your use case? If so I'll spend some more time with it

Comment: Actually I am working with an android application so how can chrome give that permission? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You can use adb to grant permissions. So it'll be as simple as a one line command right before the tests start. With this solution tho you'll need to only use the custom environment and author your own monkey test command.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the custom environment to run your own adb monkey test. Just upload an app and a dummy test package with the APPIUM_NODE test type.  Then try this yml I authored which will pull the package name, permissions, and try to auto accept them, then run the adb monkey command.

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  install:
    commands:

  pre_test:
    commands:

  test:
    commands:
      - export PACKAGE_NAME=$(aapt list -a $DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH | sed -n "/^Package Group[^s]/s/.*name=//p")
      # sanity check to make sure the package name exists
      - echo "Package name:"
      - echo "$PACKAGE_NAME"
      - adb shell pm list packages -f | grep $PACKAGE_NAME
      - aapt d permissions $DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH | cut -d "=" -f 2 | xargs -I {} adb shell pm grant $PACKAGE_NAME {} 
      # more info on this command can be found here https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey
      - adb shell monkey -v -s 1534494405270 --throttle 500 --pct-touch 45 --pct-motion 45 --pct-trackball 0 --pct-nav 0 --pct-majornav 0 --pct-syskeys 0 --pct-appswitch 10 --pct-anyevent 0 -p $PACKAGE_NAME 1000 > $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/monkey.log
      - 

  post_test:
    commands:

artifacts:
  # By default, Device Farm will collect your artifacts from following directories
  - $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR
```